# How can I take a String with a name and two values and separate it into a String containing the name and 2 doubles containing the values?

Tags: java, class, exception, io

I've written a class for a program designed to help manage a volleyball team's roster. The roster is contained in a .dat file and the players are written as follows:

```
Rachael Adams 3.36 1.93
```

My issue arises when I try to separate this string into the proper data types (the name being a string, then the first and second values being doubles for the stats).

```
public Roster(String filename) {
    players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader (fr);
        
        String line = inFile.readLine();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
        
        while(line != null) {
            String firstName = scan.next();
            String lastName = scan.next();
            double attackStat = scan.nextDouble();
            double blockStat = scan.nextDouble();
            String name = firstName + " " + lastName;
            Player newPlayer = new Player(name, attackStat, blockStat);
            players.add(newPlayer);
            line = inFile.readLine();
        }
        scan.close();
        inFile.close();
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

The program throws this exception when a Roster object is created

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
        at Roster.<init>(Roster.java:30)
        at Assignment08.openRosterFile(Assignment08.java:59)
        at Assignment08.main(Assignment08.java:18)
```

I am newer to Java and still facing a learning curve, so if there is more information needed then please let me know.

If at all possible, I would greatly appreciate an explanation as to what I did wrong rather than just a solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try Scanner.next() 2 times to get the first and last name separately? I'm talking about 2 .next() and then 2 nextDouble() if the data format is fixed with given example

Comment: Why would `nextDouble()` work at the beginning of the line? Also, you're not updating it when you read the next `line`.

Comment: @shmosel I'm not sure I understand what you mean by not updating it when I read the next `line`. It was my understanding that at the end of the `while` loop it would read the next line and update `line` then loop back to the beginning and go through them all again. Please let me know if this understanding is incorrect or you were referring to something else. I do see how `nextDouble()` wouldn't work the way I had it though. Thanks

Comment: What @shmosel correctly observed, why did you consider `Scanner scan...` to be out of while loop? When you reach the second iteration, what value of `line` is in the `scan` variable?

Comment: @Jimmy thank you. I didn't realize that the value wouldn't update in the `scan` variable. It now works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always find it easier to split the line:

```
String[] columns = line.split(" (?=\\d)";
String name = columns[0];
double attackStat = Double.parseDouble(columns[1]);
double blockStat =  Double.parseDouble(columns[2]);
```

This works by splitting on a space, but only when the next char is a digit via the *look ahead* `(?=\d)`.

This automatically caters for any number of words in the name.

Comment: Thanks! This makes more sense to do it this way in order to account for players that may have an extra space in their name.

Comment: Yep. The point is you're separating *parsing* the line from *reading* the line in from disk. If you use too much of Scanner's API, you're marrying IO with parsing, which makes your implementation hard to maintain, debug and test.